# Distributing my iOS app as an in-house app to multiple customers

Tags: ios, app-store, enterprise

I'm developing an iOS app to license to multiple customers. I do **not** want to distribute it within either the public or business app store, so it seems that my only legitimate route is the in-house app route where my customers are registered with the iOS Developer Enterprise Program and I sign my app with their provisioning profile. This presumably would allow my customers to distribute my app to their employees. Although I've read posts from a number of people doing this successfully, I have some questions:

1. I'm *not* developing custom software for any one customer. I'm therefore distributing software to multiple customers outside the App Store. Does this run afoul of Apple's intention for in-house apps? If so, is there any language from Apple that speaks to this? I found nothing in the Enterprise Developer Program Agreement that speaks to my scenario.
2. If a customer shares their certificate/provisioning profile/private with me for signing purposes, does this run afoul of Apple? A message in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577945/ios-in-house-distribution-of-app-developed-by-external-vendor?rq=1) indicates that Apple may revoke a certificate that's been shared, even though there is no malicious intent here.

To those who might wonder why I don't just use the B2B store, that route seems to present two problems for me:

- If a severe enough bug is found in my app, I need to hotfix to comply with my SLA to my customers. The App Store review period makes this difficult.
- I have an on-premises server component to my app, and its version varies across customers. Since the App Store distributes only the newest version of my app, it must be backward compatible with all existing versions of my server. Backward compatibility discipline is good practice, but it impacts my QA matrix significantly, and so I'd like to control which customer gets which app version.

My thanks for any input on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy your apps via testflightapp.
All your customers stay as tester to your project.

Comment: Will apple approve it? It violates the rules they have made.

Comment: @Minthos:Actually,it stays as a legal way in distribution of development version.All participants need to be added to development provision profile to allow them running this app after they download it.It just solve the problem of remote distribution in development phase.It won't break the running privilege limitation set by apple.